# Go to another sequence in sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have a `register` and `login` sequence diagram. I also have `login FB` sequence which have those conditions :

1. If user never login with his FB before, the system will `register` him and do `login` automatically.
2. If user have logged in with FB before, the system will just do `login` without registering him.

The problem is, the `login` and `register` already have their own respective sequence diagram. Simply copy-paste those 2 diagrams into `login FB` will solve the problem, but my diagram will be hard to read and it will be very long.

**I hope there is a way  to just say something like : go to login sequence diagram**

Please kindly help me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See also the **ref** operator for representing the **interaction use** (copy/paste) scenario as shown in [uml-diagrams.org: UML Sequence Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are nu rules about this in UML, but there are best practices. I documented mine in an article on my website: [UML Best Practice: One Operation => One Sequence Diagram](http://bellekens.com/2011/05/27/uml-best-practice-one-operation-one-sequence-diagram/)

It basically states that you make a single sequence diagram per operation. That avoids the issue of having to copy parts of the behavior into different diagrams.

Make sure that your tools retains a link between the operation and it's behavior specification so you can easily navigate from one to the other.

**EDIT:** To illustrate this for your example.
You would have a sequence diagram similar to this for loginFB

[image: loginFB]

Then you have separate sequence diagrams for register:

[image: register]

and for login

[image: login]

Make sure each sequence diagram is nested under an Interaction object, and that you link this Interaction as behavior to the respective operations.

Then it depends on your UML tool's capabilities how easy it is to navigate from the operation to its behavior (and back)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i dont quite get your answer (sorry im just learning this). And im afraid i dont have enough time to remodel my entire sequence diagrams. Can you kindly give me an example how to go to another sequence diagram? So at least i can overcome this problem for now

Comment: I've updated my answer with some examples to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it ok to call SD register just like a method?

Comment: In UML you call operations, not sequence diagrams.